# Rank of an n x n matrix A and how it relates to rank $A^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

In an old exam, I saw that if A is a 5 x 5 matrix with rank(A) = 3, then rank($A^2$) $\geq 1$. Why is this true?

Comment: Because the nullity of $A^2$ is at most twice the nullity of $A$. What have you tried, and what are you having trouble with?

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a trivial question - I'm trying to learn linear algebra on my own. Your explanation helps, but I'm still not fully understanding why the nullity of $A^2$ is at most twice the nullity of $A$.

Comment: The nullity of a matrix is the dimension of the vector subspace that it kills: that is, the dimension of the kernel, or the space that gets sent to zero.  If the matrix $A$ has nullity 2 (as it does in your question), then it sends 2 of the 5 dimensions to zero.  When we apply $A$ again (to get $A^2$), we send 2 dimensions to zero.  This could be in addition to the 2 dimensions we've already killed (meaning that the nullity of $A^2$ is 4) or we may be killing a dimension or two that's already dead (in which case the nullity of $A^2$ is less than 4).  But the nullity of $A^2$ will not exceed 4.

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, you can argue by contradiction. Assume that $A^2x=0,\forall x\in V,$ with $\dim V=5.$ So, it is

$$A(Ax)=0, \forall x\in V.$$ That is,

$$Image(A)\subset \ker(A).$$ Thus $$\dim(Image(A))\le \dim (\ker(A)).$$ Moreover $$\dim(Image(A))+\dim(\ker(A))=5.$$ So, it must be $\dim(\ker A)\ge 3$ which contradicts the fact that $rank(A)=3.$ So, it must be $rank(A^2)\ge 1.$